# Spark-submit error - Cannot load main class from JAR file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hue

I am trying to run on Hadoop with Spark but I have a "Cannot load main class from JAR file" error.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try copying `main.py` and the the additional python files to a local `file://` path instead of having them in `hdfs`.

You need to pass the additional python files with the `--py-files` argument from a local directory as well.

Assuming you copy the python files to your working directory where you are launching spark-submit from, try the following command:

```
spark-submit \
 --name "Final Project" \
 --py-files police_reports.py,three_one_one.py,vehicle_volumn_count.py \
 main.py
```